# My phone auto corrects things wrong

Tags: functionality, autocorrect

How do I fix what words my phone autocorrects. For example, when I type the word "my" it corrects it to a capital M and when I type "lost" it corrects it to Los. I find this annoying and I have to go back and correct it every time.

Comment: How are you typing? WordFlow?

Comment: What's your phone's language?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it's so annoying. I don't want to turn off autocorrect, I just want it to stop autocorrecting correct words to stupid words, eg long to Lon, if to I. 
Just typing normally, not WordFlow.
Language is English (New Zealand)
Keyboard is English (UK)
I've just reset suggestions under keyboard\advanced, and retyped the same message (in messenger app) and it didn't correct long to Lon. Maybe that's fixed it, but I have done that before.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings > keyboard > select language (keyboard) > turn off "correct misspelled words" DONE!

Comment: I think the OP wants to only keep certain words from being corrected, not all of them.